# Tensorflow AttributeError when a function is passed to another

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow. The following partial code is throwing a AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dtype'. Could someone point out what I am doing wrong and how to correctly code this?

I realize the problem is when I am trying to minimize the 'loss' within the train_function. I was assuming that during the interactive session, s, the batch_x_train and batch_y_train will be passed to the function call for 'optimizer', which calls the function 'binary_logloss', passing in the batch_y_train values. I know how to make this work without tensorflow, but I am bit confused when the graphs are involved.

```
input_X = tf.placeholder('float32', [None,64])
input_y = tf.placeholder('float32', [None,num_classes])

predicted_y = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(input_X, weights) + b)

def binary_logloss(true_y):

    if true_y ==1.:
        return tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(-tf.log(predicted_y) , axis=1))
    elif true_y == 0.:
        return tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(-tf.log(1-predicted_y) , axis=1))

def train_function(X, y):
    loss = binary_logloss(input_y)
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001).minimize(loss)
    _, c = s.run([optimizer, loss], {input_X:X, input_y:y})
    return _, c

s.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
for epoch in epochs:     
    _, c = train_function(batch_x_train, batch_y_train)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to refactor the code like this and implement a batching mechanism and I think it should execute.

```
input_X = tf.placeholder('float32', [None,64])
input_y = tf.placeholder('float32', [None,num_classes])

predicted_y = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(input_X, weights) + b)    

loss = tf.reduce_mean(-(input_y * tf.log(predicted_y) + (1 - input_y) * tf.log(1 - predicted_y)))

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001).minimize(loss)

init = (tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())

with tf.Session() as s:
    s.run(init)
    s.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for epoch in epochs:     
       # batch_x_train, batch_y_train = Batching code
       _, c = train_function(batch_x_train, batch_y_train)
```

Comment: I totally understand how to define loss as a single line formula. What I don't understand is how to write the loss formula as a function, where I am passing a value and getting a tensor in return. I am from a numpy background. I can easily pass variables to a function call and have one function call another. I am attempting to define loss in the form of a function definition and call this in optimizer. How can I achieve that in tensorflow?